Error using azure ai search performance testing tool
I'm currently working on performance testing for an AI search tool but have been running into some challenges, especially since I'm new to Terraform. I've tried several approaches, but I'm still stuck on a specific issue.
I've seen some related discussions here, and one in particular had a comment that seemed promising, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my situation. Could someone please guide me through the process or help me troubleshoot the issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-performance-testing/issues/7
Error:
> Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/bb347353-e24e-4854-b090-f7bda3b155ae.sh
Converting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vsts/work/1/s/terraform/../scripts/jtl_junit_converter.py", line 179, in
main()
File "/home/vsts/work/1/s/terraform/../scripts/jtl_junit_converter.py", line 173, in main
test_suites = create_test_suites(sys.argv[1])
File "/home/vsts/work/1/s/terraform/../scripts/jtl_junit_converter.py", line 164, in create_test_suites
junit_results = create_junit_results(jtl_results_filename)
File "/home/vsts/work/1/s/terraform/../scripts/jtl_junit_converter.py", line 106, in create_junit_results
with open(jtl_results_filename) as jmeter_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/results/results.jtl'

[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: RESULTS: Convert JMeter Results to JUnit Format

I have created a pipeline using load-test.yml file in the git repo shared above.
Code:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'RESULTS: Download Jmeter results'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(AZURE_SERVICE_CONNECTION_NAME)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    workingDirectory: ./terraform
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      RG=$(terraform output resource_group_name)
      SHARENAME=$(terraform output storage_file_share_name)
      STGKEY=$(terraform output storage_account_key)
      ACCOUNTNAME=$(terraform output storage_account_name)
      mkdir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/results
      az storage file download-batch --account-key $STGKEY --account-name $ACCOUNTNAME --destination $(JMETER_DIRECTORY_OUTPUT) --no-progress --source $SHARENAME

The above code is supposed to download the test artifacts and save it to results.jtl
the next script will convert it to another format and save it as output.xml file. but it fails with the error that results.jtl file is missing.
- script: |
    JMETER_RESULTS=$(JMETER_DIRECTORY_OUTPUT)/$(terraform output jmeter_results_file)
    JUNIT_RESULTS=$(JMETER_DIRECTORY_OUTPUT)/output.xml
    python3 ../scripts/jtl_junit_converter.py $JMETER_RESULTS $JUNIT_RESULTS
  workingDirectory: ./terraform
  displayName: 'RESULTS: Convert JMeter Results to JUnit Format'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '$(JMETER_DIRECTORY_OUTPUT)/output.xml'
    failTaskOnFailedTests: false
  displayName: 'RESULTS: Publish Load Testing Results'


Please share the code you  tried @aalimsha

I have used the exact code as mentioned in the github repo. I have added the code where it fails. Please help.

I could reproduce the issue following the instructions of this Azure Sample. The root cause appeared to be that the results.jtl file, which was required by the jtl_junit_converter.py script, was not present in the storage account. As a result, the az storage file download-batch command was unable to download the test results.

Furthermore, the jmeter.log revealed errors that suggested potential issues with the container's network connection, which possibly indicated that the tests could not have been executed as intended:
2024-08-15 09:15:03,250 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 10.0.0.4
2024-08-15 09:15:03,256 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2024-08-15 09:15:03,326 ERROR o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Failed to create engine at 10.0.0.4
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.0.4; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
...
2024-08-15 09:15:03,342 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Connection refused to host: 10.0.0.4; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2024-08-15 09:15:03,342 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Failed to configure 10.0.0.4
2024-08-15 09:15:03,344 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Stopping remote engines
2024-08-15 09:15:03,344 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been stopped
2024-08-15 09:15:03,345 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[10.0.0.4]
...
2024-08-15 09:15:03,348 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred:
org.apache.jmeter.report.config.ConfigurationException: Error in NonGUIDriver Following remote engines could not be configured:[10.0.0.4]

Considering the VNET and Container instances resources were created using the terraform template provided in this Azure Sample, it is recommended reaching out to the maintainers of the sample for further assistance. You can track the existing issue or consider raising a new one if necessary.

Is there any other tool or git repo that can be used to load test azure ai search?

That would be another topic and I am afraid I am not so familiar with Azure AI Search Service as Azure DevOps.
